# Password reset for first user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I am trying to create a reset option in my project. If user is doing their first login, it will redirect to reset page.

This is the view part

```
<div class="form-group{{ ($errors->has('cpassword')) ? 'has error' : '' }}">

    <label for="cpassword">Current Password: </label>

    <input id="cpassword" name="cpassword" type="text" class="form-control">

            @if($errors->has('cpassword'))

                {{ $errors->first('cpassword')}}

            @endif
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ ($errors->has('password')) ? 'has error' : '' }}">

    <label for="password">New Password: </label>

    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control">

            @if($errors->has('password'))

                {{ $errors->first('password')}}

            @endif

</div>

<div class="form-group{{ ($errors->has('password2')) ? 'has error' : '' }}">

    <label for="password2">Confirm Password: </label>

    <input id="password2" name="password2" type="password"   class="form-control">

            @if($errors->has('password2'))

                {{ $errors->first('password2')}}

            @endif

</div>

        {{ Form::token() }}

<div class="form-group">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">

</div>
```

in reset page we need to enter old password, new password and confirm password..

Controller part is given below

public function postReset(){

```
    $validator =Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'cpassword' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
        'password2' => 'required|min:8|same:password'
    ));
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::route('resetPassword')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    else
    {

        if (Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Auth::user()->username, 'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('cpassword'))))) {
            return 'password is resetted';
        }
    }
}
```

But if I tried to verify current password and userpasssword, their hash codes doesn't match. Is there any other methods to reset passord. I need the same view part. 
Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

The `Auth::attempt()` method needs the plain password you must not generate a hash yourself. Also Laravel's hashes can't be validated just by comparing them because every hash contains a random salt. To compare a password with it's hash you have to use `Hash::check()`. Also, while `Auth::attempt()` works `Auth::validate()` would be the better choice since your user is already logged in:

```
$credentials = array(
    'username' => Auth::user()->username,
    'password' => Input::get('cpassword')
);
if(Auth::validate($credentials)){
    return 'password is resetted';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a "forgot" password feature built in which you can use to let people reset passwords if they have forgot them.

You can find that at: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

If you want someone to be able to change their password (and they are able to remember the old one), you can do something like this:

```
if(Input::get('passwordIs')) {
            if (!Hash::check(Input::get('passwordIs'), Auth::user()->password))
                return Redirect::to('my-account/settings/')->withErrors(Lang::get('account.password-wrong'));
            else {
                if(Input::get('passwordIsNew') !== Input::get('passwordIs_confirmation'))
                    return Redirect::to('my-account/settings/')->withErrors(Lang::get('account.passwords-must-match'));
                else{
                    $password = Hash::make(Input::get('passwordIs_confirmation'));
                    $customer = Auth::user();
                    $customer->password = $password;
                    $customer->save();
                }

            }
        }
```